# Know when DOM element has changed in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am looking to figure out when a particular DOM element has been changed due to the vue data being updated.

So in the example below, I want to know when {person.favoriteColor} changes. person.favoriteColor is part of a dynamic list of people and at any point, that person can change their favorite color. The number of people can also change at any time. So for this need, I am really only looking to know when that particular person's favorite color has been updated.

```
<div v-for="person in people">
    <div>{{person.favoriteColor}}</div>
</div>
```

An idea of what I need:

```
<div v-for="(person, index) in people">
    <div v-on:update='thisHasBeenUpdated(index)'>{{person.favoriteColor}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you added Vue.JS dev tools to your browser? Here is the chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: Do you want to know when the DOM has been redrawn to reflect the data change, or do you want to know when the data item changes?

Comment: @ Roy J, I just want to know when that specific dom element has changed. Almost like an event listener for that dom element to know when something has changed/updated.

Answer (score 2):

It *sounds* like you want to use [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch):

```js
watch: {
  'person.favoriteColor': {
    handler(value, oldValue) {
      console.log(`Favorite color changed from ${oldValue} to ${value}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @jlowgren the only problem is that is treating 'person' as a key value where person is return from a vue directive